# Angular 2+ http.get() stuck in pending status

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I have a MEAN app.
Angular CLI: 7.1.4
Node: 10.1.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.1.4

recently the http requests from HttpClientModule have been getting stuck and not posting to the node server:
[Img of chrome dev tools xhr pending request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJM3D.png)

The nodejs server ( running locally and in production (azure web app) does not indicate that it ever received the request. This happens inconsistently. some times it completes other times it just hangs.
Here is a snippet of a testConnection call from Angular to the server:

Angular service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
const Headers: any = { withCredentials: true, responseType: 'json', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } };

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UserService {
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}
    loginStatus() {
      return this._http.get(`${environment.serverURL}/api/login-status`, Headers).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
    }}
```

Angular Component:

```
ngOnInit() {
this._userSvc.loginStatus().subscribe(
(result:any)=>{console.log(result)},
(error:any)=>{console.log(error)})
}
```

Node/express:

```
router.get('/login-status', (req, res, next) => {    
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.status(200).json(req.user);
  } else {
    res.status(403).json({
      success: false,
      error: 'User not Authenticated',
      message: "Please return to the login in page and try again."
    })
  }
})
```

Node is using passport to authenticate

Don't get tied up with the passport issue because its not always this route that fails. I have simple routes that do no validation and just return some text that fail too.

I tried modifying my CORS options but I've only managed to block myself.
There are times when restarting the server will allow the request to finish but not always.

Comment: Extra note* Using postman i can successfully make calls to the server everytime and I can use my browser to get to unsecured get routes too.

Comment: And obviously you are subscribing to loginStatus from any component right?

Comment: Can you show what the resolve of ${environment.serverURL}?

Comment: It's just a url it's 127.0.0.1:3000/api/login-status

Comment: It seems a RxJS thing, when you modify the question adding the .subscribe maybe will be more clear. It happens when you serve the app in a development mode?: ng serve.... or with the built version. In any case, can you show the ng serve/build sentence you are running?

Comment: Service call has been added-- The app behaves the same way when i run it live in azure vs on my local machine

Comment: I said because there are many issues like this and they are about the -aot build way, this is why I ask about how are you running

Comment: When I build for production I use command ng b --prod when Im running locally im running the server on port:3000 and the angular live debuging server on :4200 with command ng serve. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Yes, but if you are not using --aot this is not the problem. I'm only think about what version of rxjs are you using and if you can show in the service and in the component the previous code (imports)

Comment: Is it because you're not calling next() in the router.get?

Comment: No, the main thing to remember here is that it doesn't always stall. Just sometimes. So not calling a function would make it fail everytime. Also the request never hits the node route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem and i'm embarrassed to say it was in the SQL connection string for mssql.
I had ((config,error)=>{}) instead of the correct (config,(err)=>{}); This was in the de-serialize user function of passport. Nothing like looking over thousands of lines of code to spot one little problem.